# Week Dates and Week Days between two dates 6 months long

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a requirement, in which, I can provide `startDate` (`27JUL14`) and `endDate` (`30JUN15`), and `dayOfWeek`(`4`,`5`,`6`)

Day of week represent -

```
1 - Monday
2 - Tuesday
3 - Wednesday
4 - Thursday
5 - Friday
6 - Saturday
7 - Sunday
```

The duration between `startDate` and `endDate` is `6` months long, I need to get all the specific dates that match the provided `dayOfWeek` for the interval of time between `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

```
public void calculateScheduleDates(Date periodOfOperationFrom, Date periodOfOperationTo, String dow)
{
       String[] weekDays = dow.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

            int[] dayOfWeek = new int[weekDays.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++) 
            {
               try 
               {
                 dayOfWeek[i] = Integer.parseInt(weekDays[i]);

                 dateTime = (DateTime) DateTime.now().withDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek[i]);

                System.out.println("DateTime :\t"+dateTime);

               } 
               catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
            }
}
```

I have tried to get weeks (Starting date of week)

```
public void getWeekDate(String beginDate, String finishDate)
    {
        System.out.println("Begindate "+ beginDate + "\t EndDate \t"+finishDate);

        LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2014, 12, 1); 
        LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(2015, 6, 30);

/* These are date format for startDate and endDate which are not working with  27JUL14 format.
   This also needs to be changed
*/
        LocalDate thisMonday = startDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);

        if (startDate.isAfter(thisMonday)) 
        {
            startDate = thisMonday.plusWeeks(1); // start on next monday
        } 
        else 
        {
            startDate = thisMonday; // start on this monday
        }

        while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) 
        {
            dates.add(startDate);

            startDate = startDate.plusWeeks(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Size of List Of Date :\t"+dates+"\n"+dates.size());

}
```

Now I have tried to crate scheduleDates:

```
public void calculateFlightLegScheduleDates(LocalDate[] periodOfOperationFrom, String dow)
    {
        /*
         *   Process as per the Weeks received from dates list and set it to current week and process
         *  alongwith dow and for each date, loop in to set the schedule Record. 
         * */

        // the incoming weeks "periodOfOperationFrom" in list format, and I need to set the week starting date to the weeks start dates even in future and find the week dates from the dow parameter. This is the point where I am facing challenge.

    }
```

**I need this solution in Java.**

I have tried to use `jodatime` library, but couldn't get any specific result.

Note: Please note that, I need the specific dates between mentioned duration not just number of days.

Please help, I need this very much.

Comment: Can you provide a sample for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

- parse `startDate`/`endDate`
- find the first date from `startDate` marching the wanted dayOfWeek
- print that date then add 7 days and repeat until `endDate` is reached.

Sample code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        calculateScheduleDates("27JUL14", "30JUN15", DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
    }

    private static void calculateScheduleDates(final String startDate, final String endDate, final int dayOfWeek) {
        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMMy").withLocale(Locale.US);
        final LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(endDate, formatter);
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter);

        // find the first matching date
        while (start.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
            start = start.plusDays(1);
        }

        // compute and print results
        while (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
            System.out.println(start.toString(formatter).toUpperCase());
            start = start.plusDays(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
28JUL14
04AUG14
...
15DEC14
22DEC14
...
22JUN15
29JUN15
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. This is about finding the Week Starting Dates. I was able to find it. My challenge is that, after finding the week starting date, I need to find the week days of that week using dow(4,5,6) 4 - Thursday, 5 - Friday, 6 - Saturday; and the dates for those week days are required to create schedule..! which comes are String.